# What exactly makes a relationship どろどろ?

Tags: words, usage

What I understand from dictionaries is that there are somehow complicated feelings involved (Daijirin: 感情などが、複雑に絡み合って、すっきりしないさま。), but I still don't quite understand what kind of relationship would be called どろどろ. Do you have a concrete example for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ドロドロ is normally translated as muddy, dirty, or a substance of a thick consistency.

> 手がドロドロになっちゃった。 ＝ 手が汚れちゃった。
>   チョコレートが溶けてドロドロになった。

ドロドロ is to express a relationship outside marriage.

> ドロドロした男女関係 ＝ ドロ沼の不倫。

ドロドロした人間関係 ＝ backbiting, malicious gossip, envy, jealousy etc...

> 女だらけの職場のドロドロした人間関係に疲れました。

Hope this helps and made things clearer.

Comment: Consider also the noun 泥【どろ】 _"mud"_, which is reduplicated to create the adverb どろどろ.